The square of opposition and Boolean algebra
I know that Aristotle was the first to create 'The square of opposition' by expressing a syllogism as a 'The square of opposition'. And George Boole discovered the problem with Aristotle's 'The square of opposition'. But I became curious about what happened after that. Is it possible that Boolean algebra was created by George Boole after discovering the problem of 'The square of opposition'?

Boole explained his motivations in the 1847 book and they had little to do with the square of opposition:"They who are acquainted with the present state of the theory of Symbolical Algebra, are aware that the validity of the processes of analysis does not depend upon the interpretation of the symbols which are employed, but solely upon the laws of their combination... lt is upon the foundation of this general principle, that I purpose to establish the Calculus of Logic, and that I claim for it a place among the acknowledged forms of Mathematical Analysis."

@Conifold Hello, I really appreciate your comment.  However, someone said here that Boole overcame Aristotle's theory, so I was curious about what this was about and asked a question.

Boole rebuilt logic on a different basis of classes rather than subject predication to make it amenable to algebra, and he was not particularly interested in tracking correspondences between the two. If you interested in a comparison of their approaches, see Corcoran, Aristotle's Prior Analytics and Boole's Laws of thought. For a historical development of Boole's thought see Kneale, The Development of Logic, pp. 404-427.

Does the use of "square" in philosophical discussions refer to applying a negation operator twice?

@nielsnielsen No, it refers to the square shaped diagram of relationships between four types of claims in Aristotle's syllogistic.

@Conifold, all I can say is hmmm. Just hmmm.

@Conifold It's difficult to find information, so I'm asking again.  Sorry for the inconvenience. Did Boole himself never logically proved the vacuous truth? So how should I understand the text here? Since the question in this answer is related to vacuous truth, I understand that the answer also suggests that Boole strengthened Aristotle's theory while studying vacuous truth.

@Conifold I would like to use this opportunity to solidify my knowledge.  I would really appreciate it if you could leave a comment on this question.  And I apologize once again for the inconvenience.

Strictly speaking, the square of opposition was devised by later scholars such as Boethius, though it is generally accepted that it correctly represents Aristotle's teaching. The square of opposition exhibits the relationships between the four basic types of categorical proposition in Aristotle's logic, i.e. (A) All S is P, (E) No S is P, (I) Some S is P, and (O) Some S is not P.
Boole preferred to base his representation of this logic on the relations between classes. He was aware of the problem with Aristotle's logic in that it appears to take existence for granted and ignores the issue of what happens when terms are empty. It would not be correct to say Boole discovered this problem: many medieval scholars were aware of this, including William of Ockham. I wrote an answer to another question on this subject.
As to what happened after Boole's work: in modern predicate logic, the conventions for existential import differ from those of Aristotle's logic, and as a result only the diagonal relations of contradiction between A-O and E-I remain. A does not imply I; E does not imply O; A-E are not contrary; I-O are not subcontrary.
The status of the square of opposition is separate from the development of Boolean algebra. The square of opposition is concerned with propositions in subject-predicate form, e.g. All S is P. Boolean algebra is concerned with representing the relations between propositions with truth values. It expresses the logic of connectives such as conjunction, disjunction and negation. It is more closely related to Stoic logic.

Hello, Thank you for your answer! In the article here, Also 'we' didn't make this decision, we all followed one person who made it: George Boole. This is why we call this Boolean logic. I interpreted Boole to mean that in the process of logically revealing the fact that vacuous truth is really the truth, he strengthened Aristotle's The square of opposition and also came up with Boolean algebra.  I guess my understanding was wrong...

Sorry for the inconvenience.  If I understand correctly, according to this answer, didn't George Boole also touch on vacuous truth in the process of improving Aristotle's theory?

@user1274233 - G.Boole in his Mathematical Analysis of Logic (1847) discusses the Syllogism but NOT the square. The ussue called "existential import" is not discussed there.

The issue explicitly resurfaced with the B. Russell and Hugh MacColl's debate on Mind (1905) regarding The Existential Import of Propositions

MacColl asserted that the Boolean translation of "Every X is A" as XA=X does not work due to the "ivalid" 0A=0. Russell replied that there is no error "0A=0 means 'every member of the class which has no member is an A,' or "for every value of x, ' x is a member of the class which has no members' implies 'x is an A '." 1/2

This hypothetical is true for all values of x, because its hypothesis is false for all values of x, and a hypothetical with a false hypothesis is true." Thus, Russell had a clear understanding of modern concept (if not the term) of vacuous truth. 2/2

@MauroALLEGRANZA Hello, thank you for your comment.  Thanks to this, I was able to learn about confusing areas and expand my knowledge further.

@MauroALLEGRANZA In that case, it would be good to know that George Boole himself did not touch the vacuous truth while improving Aristotle's theory, but that the vacuous truth came out in the process of later scholars discussing Boole's achievements.
